# Options for creating csv structure I can work with

Tags: python, json, csv

My task is to take an output from a machine, and convert that data to json. I am using python, but the issue is the structure of the output.

From my research online, csv usually has the first row with the keys and the values in the same order underneath. Example: https://e.nodegoat.net/CMS/upload/guide-import_person_csv_notepad.png

However, the output from my machine doesn't look like this.
Mine looks like:

```
Date:,10/10/2015
Name:,"Company name"
Location:,"Company location"
Serial num:,"Serial number"
```

So the machine i'm working with is outputting each result on a new .dat file instead of appending onto a single csv with the row of keys and whatnot. Technically, yes the data is separated with csv, but not sure how to work with this.

How should I go about turning this kind of data to json? Should I look into restructuring the data to the default csv? Or is there a way I can work with this and not do any cleanup to convert this? In either case, any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I think this needs some clean up first as even JSON will not accept 10/10/2015 as a string without quotes. Then read every new data file and append the result to your CSV for processing

Comment: Split each line at `:,` then you have nice key-value-pairs for a dictionary which can be dumped as json. The values may need some mangling because of the additional quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
Date:,10/10/2015
Name:,"Company name"
Location:,"Company location"
Serial num:,"Serial number"
'''

f = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(f)
t = df.set_index(df.columns[0]).T

print(t['Location:'][0])
print(t['Serial num:'][0])
```